# Bind a count to an Ajax Pane Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, accordion

Seems like this should be an easy thing.  I have an Ajax Accordion.  Each Pane has a Header that's basically the "title" for that pane.  I'm using this accordion to show and hide comments in a blog.  Thus the Header is "Comments" but I want to modify that with a count of the comments, so it says "Comments (23) or something like that.  My SQL is returning the count as "CommentCount" so I should be able to modify this:

```
            <Panes>
            <AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="OverviewPane">
                <Header>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comments</Header>
```

... to this:

```
            <Panes>
            <AjaxToolkit:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="OverviewPane">
                <Header>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comments (<%# Eval("CommentCount")%>)</Header>
```

... and be okay, but it isn't working.  I get "Comments ()" on every blog post.

Maybe the problem is in the codebehind?

```
        Utility myUtility = new Utility();
        SqlConnection myConn = myUtility.GetConnection();
        string myCommandText = "select [KeyID],[ShadeDate],[ShadeTitle],[ShadeBody],[ShadeImage],count([Comments].[CommentID]) as CommentCount from [Shades] left join [Comments] on [Shades].[KeyID] = [Comments].[ShadeID] group by [KeyID],[ShadeTitle],[ShadeImage],[ShadeBody],[ShadeDate] order by ShadeDate DESC";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCommandText, myConn);
        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
            ShadesRepeater.DataSource = myDataTable;
            ShadesRepeater.DataBind();
        }
```